# RPI B+ with connected servo is twitching

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, servo

I am looking for some advice on how to properly get my servo working correctly. I have wired it up and it appears to be working correctly. The problem I have is with the signalling causing a twitching. The servo a TowerPro MG995 brushless. I noticed that the GPIO.PWM takes a second argument for frequency and have tried other frequencies and it only gets worse. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[I am using the tutorial found here](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch05.html)

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(18, 100)
pwm.start(5)

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        scale = Scale(frame, from_=0, to=180,
              orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.update)
        scale.grid(row=0)


    def update(self, angle):
        duty = float(angle) / 10.0 + 2.5
        pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Servo Control')
app = App(root)
root.geometry("200x50+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Servos require accurate and regular pulses.  More accurate than software timing will provide.

If you want your servo to stop twitching you have several choices.

- use some add-on hardware to generate the pulses
- find some software which can generate the needed pulses on gpio18
  (which can use special PWM hardware).  This will only be good for one
  servo.
- use one of the many modules which can provide hardware timed PWM on
  any of the gpios, e.g. my own [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/)
  which can be used from C, Python, or servoblaster, or pi-blaster, or
  RPIO.GPIO etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks I found your article earlier and the pigpio. I am learning electronics but having a hell of a lot of fun. I think I am starting to understand how the servo works.